# Общий файл для нескольких проектов

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Имеется солюшн с несколькими проектами внутри, которые собираются в разные исполняемые файлы. В проектах используются некоторые общие классы.

Возможно ли добавить общие файлы (с некоторым классом внутри) чтобы использовать сразу в нескольких проектах?
Или без дополнительных проектов в солюшне с библиотеками классов не обойтись?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разумеется можно. 
**Способ - это подключать файлы в проект по символической ссылке.** Они будут компилироваться в проекте как будто это обычные файлы. Изменения этого файла будет распостраняться на все проекты, куда эти файлы подключены.
Скриншоты и описание(на английском) приведены [здесь](https://grantwinney.com/visual-studio-add-file-as-link/)

Но данный подход лично я использую не для вынесения каких-то общих классов, потому что их разумнее вынести в отдельный проект, а например, для глобального файла AssemblyInfo, чтобы версия собираемых проектов была у всех одинаковая.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.

Comment: Git/Svn/Hq - отдельный репозиторий на эти файлы, и подключать в проект для svn как extended, для git submodule, для hq смотреть документацию :)